# How can one solve this set system

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can one solve the system:

$A-X=B$

$X-A=C$

Such that $A,B$ and $C$ $3$ set parts of $E$ and $B$ subset in $C$ and the intersection of $A$ and $C$ is empty set

$A-X=B \iff A \cap X' = B$

By Morgan logic

$A' \cup X = B'$

$X-A=C \iff X \cap A'=C$

I know that $C$ intersection $A$ is empty set means that $C$ subset of  $A'$

I'm stuck here

welcome for any edits

Comment: $B$ can only be a subset of $C$ if $B$ is empty, since every element of $B$ is not an element of $X$, and every element of $C$ is an element of $X$

Comment: @Henry can you please explain that with mathematical logic

Comment: $B = A \backslash  X \implies B \cap X = \emptyset.\,$ $ C = X \backslash  A \implies C \subseteq X.\,$  $B \cap X = \emptyset \land C \subseteq X \implies B \cap C = \emptyset.\,$ $B \cap C = \emptyset \land B \subseteq C \implies B= \emptyset.\,$

Comment: @Henry but here we need to know what is X in function of A and B and C